# Generate Swagger Document for existing NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, api, azure, server, swagger

According to [Swagger website](http://swagger.io/getting-started/), there are two approaches: Bottom-up and Top-down.

I have an existing NodeJS server that I'd like to deploy in the Azure enviroment, that require a swagger document (API APP).

Does anyone know a tool for generating the swagger using the code? Even better if you could point a tutorial. I couldn't find it.

Comment: Which framework dose your Nodejs server built on? If is Express, you can refer to https://github.com/shawngong/Swagger-Node-Express-For-Existing-APIs. To deploy Nodejs app to Azure Web Apps, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT yes I used express. I tried this project you sent, but I couldn't really understand it. In the tutorial it tells you to prepare everything, and by the way, a lot of code, and then it doesn't say what to do to generate the swagger doc....

Comment: I think you can first follow the step-by-step tutorial to build the swagger doc first, or could you tell me which step blocks you up?

Comment: Maybe you need something like this? http://mherman.org/blog/2016/05/26/swagger-and-nodejs/#.WZ7LQCgjHIU According to this, you can use module 'swagger-jsdoc' to generate swagger doc from your project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It’s not difficult to integrate Swagger in exist express applications following [this tutorial](https://github.com/shawngong/Swagger-Node-Express-For-Existing-APIs).

Generally, we can follow these steps:

1. Add the dependencies in our  `package.json`, and run `npm install` to install them. The dependencies should be:

   ```
   "dependencies": {
           "swagger-node-express": "~2.0",
           "minimist": "*",
           "body-parser": "1.9.x",
           ...
   }
   ```
2. Download the zip project of [Swagger-UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), copy the `dist` folder into the root directory of our project, the directory should almost like:

[image]

3. Introduce the dependencies at the beginnng of `app.js`:

   ```
   var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
   var swagger = require("swagger-node-express");
   var bodyParser = require( 'body-parser' );
   ```
4. Set up a subpath for swagger doc:

   ```
   var subpath = express();
   app.use(bodyParser());
   app.use("/v1", subpath);
   swagger.setAppHandler(subpath);
   ```
5. Make sure that `/dist` is able to serve static files in express:
   `app.use(express.static('dist'));`
6. Set the info for API:

   ```
   swagger.setApiInfo({
       title: "example API",
       description: "API to do something, manage something...",
       termsOfServiceUrl: "",
       contact: "yourname@something.com",
       license: "",
       licenseUrl: ""
   });
   ```
7. Introduce `/dist/index.html` for swagger UI:

   ```
   subpath.get('/', function (req, res) {
       res.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
   });
   ```
8. Complete the swagger configurations:

   ```
   swagger.configureSwaggerPaths('', 'api-docs', '');

   var domain = 'localhost';
   if(argv.domain !== undefined)
       domain = argv.domain;
   else
       console.log('No --domain=xxx specified, taking default hostname "localhost".');
   var applicationUrl = 'http://' + domain;
   swagger.configure(applicationUrl, '1.0.0');
   ```
9. Configure doc file dependence in `/dist/index.html`:

   ```
   if (url && url.length > 1) {
       url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
   } else {
       <del>url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json";</del>
       url = "/api-docs.json";
   }
   ```
10. Create `api-docs.json` file with the info of your APIs, put it in the `dist` folder.

Run the Express app on local, visit `http://localhost:3000/v1`, we can check the swagger doc.

Here is my [test sample repo](https://github.com/Walk4Muscle/Swagger-node-express3-sample) for your reference.

Comment: This doesn't "generate" anything. It simply serves swaggerUI alongside an app?

Comment: I generated simple swagger.json from my express 3 apps to import to Postman app via https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-swagger-export package. I built it for myself, but maybe it useful for someone.

Comment: Will Swagger Editor will work with this after `swagger project editor`?

Comment: Downvote, because it is not generating, it is manual work, and not "not difficult".

Answer (score 20):

Question is a bit old but still. It is possible to generate completely automatically Swagger (OpenAPI) specification just by embedding analysis middleware like this: https://github.com/mpashkovskiy/express-oas-generator

```
const express = require('express');    
const expressOasGenerator = require('express-oas-generator');
let app = express();
expressOasGenerator.init(app, {});
```

run some client or REST API tests agains your service and open http://host:port/api-docs

Comment: Hi thanks for the info i am also using express-oas-generator to make api documentation its working but in response it will not update in ui  some times it update some time its not can you help to fix that issues

Comment: sure, may I ask you to create an issue and describe the problem in details here: https://github.com/mpashkovskiy/express-oas-generator/issues ?

Comment: Hi, so you're the creator of `express-oas-generator`. I love it and use it in my Express app. One thing I miss is the ability to populate body, headers, query, etc. dynamically like Fastify. Like you add a middleware function, passing a schema as its parameter, and it gets passed to OAS Gen. Any plans for adding this functionality in a future version?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, your options are:

1. Using [swagger-node-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-node-express) which is very cumbersome in my opinion.
2. Writing up the swagger document manually yourself with the help of [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) as suggested in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31332524/1998422)

If you go for option 2, you could use [swagger-ui-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express) to generate the swagger-ui

Answer (score 2):

A lot of developers are still having this problem so I built an open-source tool to help -- the tool is kind of like Git for APIs. It works by running a proxy while you're developing the API, analyzing the traffic, and updating the spec for you as the API's behavior changes. Hopefully, the workflow saves you a lot of time: https://github.com/opticdev/optic

Answer (score 2):

Most alternatives require some sort of API specification through Json, Yaml or even embedded in JSdocs. On the other hand there are some runtime analyzers intercepting HTTP requests and building that specification on-demand.

[express-sitemap-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sitemap-html) follows a different approach inspecting the express object and its routes at setup time. Thus it always provides an up-to-date swagger UI for installed routes on existing express instance.

```js
const sitemap = require('express-sitemap-html')
...
sitemap.swagger('Title', app) // app is an express instance
```

Then get swagger UI from your domain `/api-docs`.

Comment: could you help to clarify, please, why after generation routes looks like `/apiauth` and `/apiuser`  instead of `/api/auth` and `/api/user`?

Comment: Hi @MikeDatsko I am not getting your doubt. You may check the example provided in https://github.com/fmcarvalho/express-sitemap-html repository. Run it with `node example\app.js` and you may check the sitemap in `http://localhost:3000/sitemap` or `http://localhost:3000/api-docs/#/`.

Comment: yes, I did like in example, and this is what I see there https://www.dropbox.com/s/9erszn17rf4v446/Screenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: Which line number did you find a route with path auth or user? https://github.com/fmcarvalho/express-sitemap-html/blob/master/example/app.js

Comment: the difference with your example is that I used `app.use`. can it be the root cause of the issue?