# How to document existing nodejs APIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

New to Node, and really frustrated with multiple libraries to do the same thing. I am going no where.

I have existing Node + express application, and need to integrate swagger docs. 
Most useful thread I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534488/generate-swagger-document-for-existing-nodejs-server). But it just expects to have parallel api-docs.json file. This is not generated automatically.

I want to document each API in the controller, and want to generate the documents. Can someone point me to better resource?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic in SO. Consider insisting on an approach and ask once you find a particular issue.

Comment: you can use this http://apidocjs.com/ for documentation, i didn't use add this as a answer as this is a very opinionated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I was able to make it work with [swagger-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc)

Steps

- Add [Swagger-UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) package
- Add swagger-ui dependency

  `npm install -g swagger-ui`
- Configure swagger in your server.js file

  `var swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
   var options = {
      swaggerDefinition: {
        info: {
           title: 'Hello World', // Title (required) 
           version: '1.0.0', // Version (required) 
        },
      },
      apis: ['./routes.js'], // Path to the API docs 
   };
   var swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);
   app.get('/api-docs.json', function(req, res) {
     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     res.send(swaggerSpec);
   });
   app.use('/api/docs',express.static('./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist'));`
- Add swagger comments to your controller functions

`/**
 * @swagger
 * resourcePath: /api
 * description: All about API
 */`

`/**
 * @swagger
 * /login:
 *   post:
 *     description: Login to the application
 *     produces:
 *       - application/json
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: username
 *         description: Username to use for login.
 *         in: formData
 *         required: true
 *         type: string
 *       - name: password
 *         description: User's password.
 *         in: formData
 *         required: true
 *         type: string
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: login
 */
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body);
});`

- Swagger documentation available at 
  http://localhost:3000/api/docs/?url=/api-docs.json