# Generate Swagger Documentation for existing NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to document my API using Swagger, but if I do the documentation by myself and manually, I'll spent a lot of time, and then I saw this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534488/generate-swagger-document-for-existing-nodejs-server), and the last answer is about the [express-oas-generator](https://github.com/mpashkovskiy/express-oas-generator) that seem's to be a good tool.

Generated my documentation with success, but the `POST` didn't made my Payload documentation, and without this, some developer could thought that my `POST` don't need a payload to send

All that I did was following the documentation, made some test's using the API and call the methods using POSTMAN. The express-oas-generator, generates the documentation, but without the payload in POST method.

Someone has already pass through this ?