# Swagger is not generating API documentation for the `Node.js` project, why?

Tags: node.js, rest, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Swagger specification document is not being generated from Swagger integration into `Node.js` project as a sub project. However, `SwaggerUI` is up and running. If we provide say swagger.json or api-docs.json file then it is rendering specified `REST API calls`.
My requirement is to generate the `API` document for existing project. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300756/can-swagger-autogenerate-its-yaml-based-on-existing-express-routes/31332524#31332524) for help in deciding how to generate Swagger docs for a project.

You can either manually create the docs for your API and have Swagger UI serve them, or you can use a node package like [swagger-node-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-node-express) which will do most of the documenting automatically.  See the link above for pros and cons of each of these options.

Comment: I have tried swagger-node-express that before, but I am not able to get the documentation also it doesn't through any meaningful error.
I am looking for some utility that will read all my routes and create the API doc automatically.